# How can I format this array of arrays into a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

[Here is the data](http://cryptocoincharts.info/fast/period.php?pair=ETH-USDT&market=poloniex&time=alltime&resolution=1d)

Originally I was using openpyxl and the .split() method to separate the arrays of data. This still leaves some formatting, but most of all I would really like to able to do this with pandas.

Any help would be great, thanks !

EDIT: Also if anyone knows some good tutorials for pandas beginners that would be great !

EDIT2:

Ami Tavory's answer throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\Python\Coursera\Computational Finance\CAPM\Scatter\JSONparser.py", line 7, in <module>
    data = json.load(open('ETH_USD.txt'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 13409 - line 1 column 13426 (char 13408 - 13425)
```

EDIT3: this is my code:

```
# Import the JSON parser
import json
# and pandas
import pandas as pd

# Assuming the data is in stuff.txt
data = json.load(open('ETH_USD.txt'))
#bpd.DataFrame(data)

[Finished in 1.1s]
```

EDIT3: this worked like a treat:

```
# Import the JSON parser
import json
# and pandas
import pandas as pd

URL = 'http://cryptocoincharts.info/fast/period.php?pair=ETH-USDT&market=poloniex&time=alltime&resolution=1d'
data = pd.read_json(URL)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

data.to_csv('ETH_USD_PANDAS.csv')
```

Comment: Well, since the original URL works, and it worked for me on my local computer when I downloaded it, I'd say the suspect is the way you downloaded it, no? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways. Based on the format of the text to which you linked, here is the one I think is easiest:

```
# Import the JSON parser
import json
# and pandas
import pandas as pd

# Assuming the data is in stuff.txt
data = json.load(open('stuff.txt'))
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Ahh it's a JSON! man that's awesome, thankyou so much. Btw, how did you know it was a JSON?

Comment: For a non commercial, probably stable link to a solid pandas tutorial, https://github.com/jvns/pandas-cookbook.

Comment: ?! That's strange  - it loaded by me with no problems.

Comment: Hmm yeah that's strange it doesn't work on mine, anyone got any ideas as to why ? Also @MathBio thanks for to book recommendation i'll check it out !

Comment: @Ami Tavory hey, thanks again. Also thanks for letting me know I should upvote / accept the answer, i wasn't aware i should this latter